# Apply multiple coupon on magento 2 cart

Tags: magento-2.1

I am working on apply multiple coupon on cart page in magento 2. I want to know the observer event where i can apply my logic for applying multiple coupon.

Comment: This is not a standard feature of M2. Maybe you should show your progress so far in order to get an idea of where you're going.

Comment: okay, but i am new in magento 2 and want to know the events for apply coupons